# how can i solve this The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar

```
 ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();


ListView.builder(
  ……
  ……..

CupertinoScrollbar(
controller: scrollController,
  thumbVisibility: true, 
  child: ListView.builder(
controller: scrollController,
……
)
)


 )
```

## how can i solve this (The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.)

Update: The solution to the problem has been updated like this

```
ScrollController outerScrollController = ScrollController();
ScrollController innerScrollController = ScrollController();

ListView.builder(
  controller: outerScrollController,
  // other properties
  // ...
)

CupertinoScrollbar(
  controller: innerScrollController,
  thumbVisibility: true,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: outerScrollController,
    // other properties
    // ...
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition" occurs when attempting to attach the same **`ScrollController`** instance to multiple **`Scrollable`** widgets. It is important to associate each **`ScrollController`** with only one **`Scrollable`** widget at a time.

In your code, you have attached the `scrollController` to both the outer `ListView.builder` and the `ListView.builder` inside `CupertinoScrollbar`. To resolve the problem, you can create separate instances of `ScrollController` for each `ListView.builder`:

```
ScrollController outerScrollController = ScrollController();
ScrollController innerScrollController = ScrollController();

ListView.builder(
  controller: outerScrollController,
  // other properties
  // ...
)

CupertinoScrollbar(
  controller: innerScrollController,
  thumbVisibility: true,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: innerScrollController,
    // other properties
    // ...
  )
)
```

By using separate **`ScrollController`** instances, you ensure that each **`ListView.builder`** has its own controller and avoids the error.

Comment: I am still getting this error when I implement your solution "The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition."

Comment: have you checked if the ScrollController is being used in any other Scrollable widgets or scroll-related operations outside the code snippet you provided? Make sure you are not inadvertently using the same ScrollController elsewhere and 
Ensure that the ScrollController is not being attached to multiple Scrollable widgets indirectly. For example, if you have nested ListView.builder or SingleChildScrollView widgets, make sure each one has its own unique ScrollController.

Comment: I made a small change in your solution and updated the final version in the question section.